# Ruby on Rails: Should a single field ever get its own model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modeling

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I have a relatively simple question. I'm modeling users. I want users to be able to have a short "profile message" that they can edit and that gets displayed on their profiles. Would it make sense to make ProfileMessage its own model? Or, should profile_message be one column in a table that contains user settings?

I feel like an entire model just for one string is a little bit overkill and if I start going that route, I'm going to end up with so many models that things become cumbersome.

What does the community think?

Comment: I think you already know the answer. By adding a new model just for the profile message it would be an overkill and will add more weight to your queries. Just go with a string/text field on the User model and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your data structure as simple as possible when starting out.  For a profile message, it doesn't make much sense to have it be it's own model.  Only if profile_message were to later on have it's own set of attributes and behaviors, or if users could have more than one profile message...then I would consider moving it to a separate model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'll let the community decide which is the best answer, because I don't feel qualified to judge.

Answer (score 0):

Table joins in SQL consumes a lot of resources when you are not using them properly. In your case i think that making a new model only for the one profile_message is not a good practice.However, it should be implemented inside the user/profile model.

This approach is going to make accessing the message faster, on the other hand if you are using a whole table for the profile_message will make the response time slower because you will need to look for it every time in the profileMessages table which will take more time depending on the number of entries in that table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'll let the community decide which is the best answer, because I don't feel qualified to judge.